# How to Make Inline SVG Scale to Parent Element with CSS

Tags: css, svg, responsiveness

I'm trying to make an inline SVG element scale to a parent element with a fixed size. I feel like I've been able to do this in the past, but having trouble doing it now for some reason. When I load the page, the SVG is HUGE and gets clipped by the parent container. How can I force the SVG to be 100% of the width of the container, and adjust accordingly for the height?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amacarthur89/e52vk9vc/6/) demonstrating the following example code.

My HTML:

```
 <div class="github-logo">
   <svg height="1024" width="2856.857" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">     
     <path d="M552.73 332.135H311.557c-6.205 0-11.25 5.045-11.25 11.297v117.887c0 6.252 5.045 11.272 11.25 11.272h94.109v146.542c0 0-21.145 7.057-79.496 7.057-68.914 0-165.156-25.244-165.156-236.795 0-211.642 100.197-239.491 194.307-239.491 81.465 0 116.514 14.304 138.869 21.241 7.01 2.203 13.404-4.831 13.404-11.105L534.543 46.129999999999995c0-2.912-1.041-6.417-4.262-8.785C521.186 30.951999999999998 465.865 0 326.168 0 165.133 0 0 68.48699999999997 0 397.757 0 726.979 189.051 776 348.381 776c131.883 0 212.021-56.314 212.021-56.314 3.268-1.801 3.6-6.395 3.6-8.479V343.432C563.955 337.227 558.887 332.135 552.73 332.135zM1772.381 28.134000000000015h-135.695c-6.252 0-11.271 5.044-11.271 11.296v262.393h-211.619V39.42999999999995c0-6.252-5.068-11.296-11.178-11.296h-135.838c-6.111 0-11.084 5.044-11.084 11.296v710.473c0 6.299 5.021 11.32 11.084 11.32h135.838c6.203 0 11.178-5.068 11.178-11.32V446.067h211.619l-0.475 303.883c0 6.3 5.021 11.272 11.084 11.272h135.885c6.252 0 11.131-5.068 11.131-11.272l0.473-710.521C1783.607 33.178 1778.539 28.134000000000015 1772.381 28.134000000000015zM714.949 44.236999999999966c-48.357 0-87.574 39.572-87.574 88.403 0 48.855 39.217 88.428 87.574 88.428s87.527-39.572 87.527-88.428C802.477 83.80999999999995 763.307 44.236999999999966 714.949 44.236999999999966zM792.861 272.126c0-6.205-5.02-11.344-11.131-11.344H646.32c-6.348 0-11.746 6.394-11.746 12.67 0 0 0 394.654 0 469.867 0 13.735 8.572 17.903 19.703 17.903 0 0 57.688 0 121.959 0 13.311 0 16.814-6.536 16.814-18.188-0.094-25.197-0.094-123.808-0.094-142.942C792.861 581.905 792.861 272.126 792.861 272.126zM2297.973 261.84799999999996h-134.701c-6.158 0-11.084 5.092-11.084 11.344v348.31c0 0-34.244 25.197-82.934 25.197-48.547 0-61.525-22.024-61.525-69.719 0-47.553 0-303.835 0-303.835 0-6.252-5.068-11.345-11.131-11.345h-136.643c-6.252 0-11.178 5.093-11.178 11.345 0 0 0 185.521 0 326.807 0 141.284 78.766 175.906 186.99 175.906 88.854 0 160.609-49.115 160.609-49.115s3.363 25.766 5.068 28.844c1.422 3.078 5.447 6.158 9.852 6.158h86.58c6.158 0 11.178-5.069 11.178-11.321l0.379-477.278C2309.15 266.9390000000001 2304.129 261.84799999999996 2297.973 261.84799999999996zM2666.932 245.83899999999994c-76.539 0-128.592 34.148-128.592 34.148V39.42999999999995c0-6.252-5.068-11.296-11.131-11.296h-136.264c-6.109 0-11.131 5.044-11.131 11.296l-0.379 710.521c0 6.3 5.068 11.272 11.225 11.272 0 0 94.773 0 94.869 0 4.215 0 7.389-2.179 9.805-5.968 2.369-3.837 5.73-32.775 5.73-32.775s55.557 52.763 161.035 52.763c123.807 0 194.758-62.804 194.758-281.906C2856.859 274.51800000000003 2743.471 245.83899999999994 2666.932 245.83899999999994zM2613.791 646.225c-46.701-1.421-78.34-22.64-78.34-22.64v-225.07c0 0 31.307-19.206 69.672-22.593 48.547-4.31 95.438 10.326 95.438 126.13C2700.322 624.059 2679.199 648.166 2613.791 646.225zM1185.125 643.667c-5.969 0-21.219 2.368-36.85 2.368-49.92 0-66.971-23.256-66.971-53.331 0-30.218 0-199.85 0-199.85h101.926c6.252 0 11.178-5.044 11.178-11.343v-109.48c0.094-6.299-4.926-11.344-11.178-11.344h-101.926l-0.143-134.535c0-5.092-2.699-7.625-8.572-7.625H933.861c-5.352 0-8.336 2.391-8.336 7.578v139.035c0 0-69.576 16.79-74.266 18.188-4.641 1.326-8.051 5.684-8.051 10.822v87.408c0 6.252 5.068 11.344 11.178 11.344h71.139c0 0 0 91.34 0 210.222 0 156.109 109.553 171.455 183.439 171.455 33.723 0 74.076-10.988 80.848-13.356 4.074-1.421 6.395-5.637 6.395-10.136l0.047-96.101C1196.254 648.688 1190.998 643.572 1185.125 643.667z"/>
   </svg>
 </div>
```

My CSS:

```
 .github-logo{
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: blue;
 }

 .github-logo svg {
     max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably have a viewbox on that SVG and probably an aspect ratio rather than height & width defined in the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you do not have a `viewbox` defined (or an Aspect Ratio but that's another story) but instead the SVG has defined height and width.

Setting this the view box to something more appropriate seems to work.

```
  <svg viewbox="0 0 2856.857 1024" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

```css
.github-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.github-logo svg {
  width: 100%;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="github-logo">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 2856.857 1024" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M552.73 332.135H311.557c-6.205 0-11.25 5.045-11.25 11.297v117.887c0 6.252 5.045 11.272 11.25 11.272h94.109v146.542c0 0-21.145 7.057-79.496 7.057-68.914 0-165.156-25.244-165.156-236.795 0-211.642 100.197-239.491 194.307-239.491 81.465 0 116.514 14.304 138.869 21.241 7.01 2.203 13.404-4.831 13.404-11.105L534.543 46.129999999999995c0-2.912-1.041-6.417-4.262-8.785C521.186 30.951999999999998 465.865 0 326.168 0 165.133 0 0 68.48699999999997 0 397.757 0 726.979 189.051 776 348.381 776c131.883 0 212.021-56.314 212.021-56.314 3.268-1.801 3.6-6.395 3.6-8.479V343.432C563.955 337.227 558.887 332.135 552.73 332.135zM1772.381 28.134000000000015h-135.695c-6.252 0-11.271 5.044-11.271 11.296v262.393h-211.619V39.42999999999995c0-6.252-5.068-11.296-11.178-11.296h-135.838c-6.111 0-11.084 5.044-11.084 11.296v710.473c0 6.299 5.021 11.32 11.084 11.32h135.838c6.203 0 11.178-5.068 11.178-11.32V446.067h211.619l-0.475 303.883c0 6.3 5.021 11.272 11.084 11.272h135.885c6.252 0 11.131-5.068 11.131-11.272l0.473-710.521C1783.607 33.178 1778.539 28.134000000000015 1772.381 28.134000000000015zM714.949 44.236999999999966c-48.357 0-87.574 39.572-87.574 88.403 0 48.855 39.217 88.428 87.574 88.428s87.527-39.572 87.527-88.428C802.477 83.80999999999995 763.307 44.236999999999966 714.949 44.236999999999966zM792.861 272.126c0-6.205-5.02-11.344-11.131-11.344H646.32c-6.348 0-11.746 6.394-11.746 12.67 0 0 0 394.654 0 469.867 0 13.735 8.572 17.903 19.703 17.903 0 0 57.688 0 121.959 0 13.311 0 16.814-6.536 16.814-18.188-0.094-25.197-0.094-123.808-0.094-142.942C792.861 581.905 792.861 272.126 792.861 272.126zM2297.973 261.84799999999996h-134.701c-6.158 0-11.084 5.092-11.084 11.344v348.31c0 0-34.244 25.197-82.934 25.197-48.547 0-61.525-22.024-61.525-69.719 0-47.553 0-303.835 0-303.835 0-6.252-5.068-11.345-11.131-11.345h-136.643c-6.252 0-11.178 5.093-11.178 11.345 0 0 0 185.521 0 326.807 0 141.284 78.766 175.906 186.99 175.906 88.854 0 160.609-49.115 160.609-49.115s3.363 25.766 5.068 28.844c1.422 3.078 5.447 6.158 9.852 6.158h86.58c6.158 0 11.178-5.069 11.178-11.321l0.379-477.278C2309.15 266.9390000000001 2304.129 261.84799999999996 2297.973 261.84799999999996zM2666.932 245.83899999999994c-76.539 0-128.592 34.148-128.592 34.148V39.42999999999995c0-6.252-5.068-11.296-11.131-11.296h-136.264c-6.109 0-11.131 5.044-11.131 11.296l-0.379 710.521c0 6.3 5.068 11.272 11.225 11.272 0 0 94.773 0 94.869 0 4.215 0 7.389-2.179 9.805-5.968 2.369-3.837 5.73-32.775 5.73-32.775s55.557 52.763 161.035 52.763c123.807 0 194.758-62.804 194.758-281.906C2856.859 274.51800000000003 2743.471 245.83899999999994 2666.932 245.83899999999994zM2613.791 646.225c-46.701-1.421-78.34-22.64-78.34-22.64v-225.07c0 0 31.307-19.206 69.672-22.593 48.547-4.31 95.438 10.326 95.438 126.13C2700.322 624.059 2679.199 648.166 2613.791 646.225zM1185.125 643.667c-5.969 0-21.219 2.368-36.85 2.368-49.92 0-66.971-23.256-66.971-53.331 0-30.218 0-199.85 0-199.85h101.926c6.252 0 11.178-5.044 11.178-11.343v-109.48c0.094-6.299-4.926-11.344-11.178-11.344h-101.926l-0.143-134.535c0-5.092-2.699-7.625-8.572-7.625H933.861c-5.352 0-8.336 2.391-8.336 7.578v139.035c0 0-69.576 16.79-74.266 18.188-4.641 1.326-8.051 5.684-8.051 10.822v87.408c0 6.252 5.068 11.344 11.178 11.344h71.139c0 0 0 91.34 0 210.222 0 156.109 109.553 171.455 183.439 171.455 33.723 0 74.076-10.988 80.848-13.356 4.074-1.421 6.395-5.637 6.395-10.136l0.047-96.101C1196.254 648.688 1190.998 643.572 1185.125 643.667z"
    />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e52vk9vc/17/)

[**SVG ViewPort and View Box**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/e52vk9vc/15/
Your svg needed height and width setting to 100% and the viewbox setting to it's default dimensions. Ive also added in some standard xml stuff that should be included in svgs.

`<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2856.857 1024" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%">`

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate how setting the width & height to 100% keeps the SVG centered the parent. Much easier than dealing with CSS to fix that later.